# Binding Last Row of DataTable to a Label in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatable, binding

I am having trouble binding the last row of a data table to a label. 
I can bind the first row to a label as below (XAML) , but I cannot figure a way to bind the last row.

`<Label DataContext="{Binding dataTable}" Content="{Binding Path=Rows[0][DataColumn]}"/>`

Comment: I do understand that I can bind the datatable and use a converter to get the last row value, but I was wondering if there is a way to do access the last row in XAML

Comment: If you use a converter, are you sure that it works if you add new rows to that datatable? 

I don`t think that there is a way to get the last row, from Xaml. Another approach would be to make a property in the ViewModel (where the datatable is), that contains this last row value, and NotifyPropertyChanged when you add a new row.

Comment: The converter approach will work if you raise property changed event after updating the table. Yes Storing the value in the viewmodel is also a valid approach. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this class should do the trick:

```
 class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion Members

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The property that contains the LastRowInformation
    /// </summary>
    public String this[string ColumnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (DataTable == null || DataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
                return String.Empty;

            return DataTable.Rows[DataTable.Rows.Count - 1][ColumnName].ToString();
        }
    }

    public DataTable DataTable { get; private set; }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Constructor

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DataTable = new DataTable();

        // Adding mock data
        DataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName");
        DataTable.Rows.Add("R1");
        DataTable.Rows.Add("R2");
        DataTable.Rows.Add("R3");

        // Updates the Property when a row is changed / added.
        DataTable.RowChanged += Data_RowChanged;
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Events

    private void Data_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("");
    }

    #endregion Events

    #region Methods

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

You Bind that class to your view, and use it like this in the xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding [ColumnName]}"/>
</Grid>
```